# FadeInImage in BoxDecoration

Tags: flutter

I love the FadeInImage

I can do this

```
child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
    image: 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
    placeholder: 'assets/images/loading.gif',
  ),
```

I want to use the `FadeInImage` in a `BoxDecoration` as below.

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
  image: DecorationImage(
    image: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
        '${document['image']}'),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

I get this error:

`The argument type 'FadeInImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'`

How would I go about it?

Use Case

In a carousel, put in placeholder, before network loaded image comes in

Here's my carousel Widget (I'm using the `carousel_slider` package for Flutter)

```
  Widget _carouselSlider(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('events').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return CarouselSlider(
              height: 150.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              enableInfiniteScroll: false,
              items: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                print('Listing the documents: $document');
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print('I am clicked');
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/detail');
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 5.0, right: 5.0, bottom: 20.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage('${document['image']}'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '${document['name']}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

So, for the part

```
image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage('${document['image']}'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
```

I wish to have a placeholder approach, instead of only the text until network loaded image arrives.

Comment: Sorry you can't use `FadeInImage` in `DecorationImage`, if you can tell me your use case, I will try to solve it using `FadeInImage`.

Comment: Sure @CopsOnRoad I've updated the question with my use case.

Comment: OK, great, will [this](https://imgur.com/q4C6nUE) work? Here I have used loading before we get some data, once we have data, I show chocolate placeholder and after this we have final image which is of pool.

Comment: I guess that would do. Any sample example code?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: _myFuture(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) return _yourWidget();
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget _yourWidget() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: FadeInImage(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            placeholder: AssetImage(chocolateImage),
            image: NetworkImage(poolImageUrl),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        Center(child: Text('Pool', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _myFuture() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10500));
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: That was quick. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: So I just ended up using a `Card` widget, so as I could use the `FadeInImage`. Seemed the quickest and simplest.

Answer (score 4):

I achieved something similar. This image is a hero image at the top of the page, hence the height. The combination of width and `BoxFit.cover` make the image cover the viewport.
The loader is (visually) hidden when the image loads.

```
final imageWithLoader = Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      Center(
        child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
            image: library.url,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    ]));
```

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote? I'm new to Flutter and would appreciate more constructive feedback to help me learn.

Comment: he asked how to use it in BoxDecoration not in Container!

Comment: the exclamation point isn't very constructive

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can use the .image method on the image to return a provider.

```
DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
          image:
            FadeInImage(
              placeholder:
                  AssetImage('assets/images/global/800x.gif'),
              image: <<some image provider>>,
            ).image,
        ),
```

Comment: This returns the image once loaded, but loses the placeholder and the animation

Answer (score 0):

It's because `FadeInImage` it not a type of `ImageProvider` widget, you need to use `AssetImage`, `NetworkImage`... inside `DecorationImage`.

Outside the `DecorationImage`, like in a Container's child, you can use it as well.

e.g.

```
       Container(
          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
            image: product.thumbnail,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
```

To know more about this widget, check it this:

[Flutter Widget of The Week - FadeIn Image](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pK738Pg9cxc)

Comment: That, Im aware of. I want to use FadeInImage *in* DecorationImage. Or in other words, I want a placeholder mechanism like FadeInImage, to use in DecorationImage.

Answer (score 0):

I am late in the party. But here is my solution If you want to style FadeInImage, you can not use ***FadeInImage.assetNetwork***. We will just use ***FadeInImage*** inside a ***Container()***.

With the Container(), you can style using BoxDecoration. We know that ***BoxDecoration*** takes ***DecorationImage***. For DecorationImage property, we will provide ***FadeInImage***.

And at the same time we will use ***AssetImage()*** for the ***placeholder*** and ***NetworkImage()*** for the ***image***. Get the complete code here https://www.dbestech.com/tutorials/flutter-fadeinimage-for-networking-image

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete example of FadeInImage inside BoxDecoration,

```
Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
      image: DecorationImage(
           image: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
               image:'<ImageURL>',
               height: 200,
               width: double.infinity,
               placeholder: kTransparentImage,
               fit: BoxFit.cover,
               ).image,
           ),
        ),
        child: Widget()
    ),
```